# Optaplanner; Why the Memory use tag in the html page does not work?

Tags: optaplanner

Using the benchmark statistics I obtain the memory use tag in the html page but it does not give me any related graph, the part of my benchmark xml file is:

```
<problemBenchmarks>
  <xStreamAnnotatedClass>org.optaplanner.examples.myproblem.domain.MySchedule</xStreamAnnotatedClass>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[26]Day(16.01.15-10.02.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[25]Day(16.01.15-9.02.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[20]Day(16.01.15-4.02.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[15]Day(16-30.01.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[10]Day(16-25.01.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[5]Day(16-20.01.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[2]Day(16,17.01.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/myproblem/unsolved/[1]Day(16.01.15).xml</inputSolutionFile>
  <problemStatisticType>BEST_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
  <problemStatisticType>STEP_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
  <problemStatisticType>CALCULATE_COUNT_PER_SECOND</problemStatisticType>
  <problemStatisticType>BEST_SOLUTION_MUTATION</problemStatisticType>
  <problemStatisticType>MOVE_COUNT_PER_STEP</problemStatisticType>
  <problemStatisticType>MEMORY_USE</problemStatisticType>
  <singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_BEST_SCORE</singleStatisticType>
  <singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_STEP_SCORE</singleStatisticType>
  <singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_BEST_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>
  <singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_STEP_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>
</problemBenchmarks>
```

Where is my wrong action?

A screen shot for the Memory_Use:

[image]

A Screen shot for the Best_Score, note that when I clicked the memory use tab no change from using the best score tab:

[image]

Comment: Can you also take a screenshot of what the html shows under the problem statistics? For each problem file there should be a set of tabs and in those tabs the memory use tab.

Comment: If it indeed doesn't show up, that's a bug and I need a way to reproduce it so I can fix it. But at this point, I just think you're looking at the wrong place in the report.

Comment: the tab appears but when I click it no data is shown, the previous data is still exist on the graph.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the index.html. What version of OptaPlanner and what version of Chrome?

Comment: If (and only if) it reproduces with `6.3.0.Final` or later, submit a [new jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) and attach a benchmark report that demonstrates the problem as a zip file. I should be able to fix it quickly.

Comment: Optaplanner version 6.2.0 and Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: where I can find the index.html file in my program?

Comment: with index.html I mean the benchmark report (the html page you got open in Chrome)

Comment: can I modify any thing to solve my problem?

Comment: If (and only if) it reproduces with 6.3.0.Final or later, submit a new jira and attach a benchmark report that demonstrates the problem as a zip file.

Comment: what I can do to overcome my problem using version 6.2.0? because I don't want to change the used version till I finish my project.

Comment: Look for the png files in the benchmark report dir. [Upgrading is easy though](http://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/upgradeRecipe6.3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour looks similar as described in [this jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-497): a bug in the generated anchor id's. But I can't reproduce it in `6.4.0.SNAPSHOT`, so I suspect it was fixed a long time ago (that jira can't have fixed it).

**You should upgrade from 6.2 to at least 6.3.**